# Chrome DevTools Local Overrides Not Reflecting Changes in Webpack Source Maps

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, overriding, source-maps

I've been experimenting with the Chrome DevTools' local overrides feature to modify a specific JavaScript file on a website. However, I've run into an interesting situation that I need some guidance on.

After successfully identifying the target JavaScript file and enabling local overrides, I made changes to the local version of the file, expecting those changes to be reflected on the website. However, the website still seems to fetch the original file from the server, rather than using my modified local version.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me understand and resolve this issue. Thank you for your assistance.

Interestingly, I found a workaround by locating the original minified file through the "Reveal in Network panel," editing it directly, and saving it for local overrides. This seems to fix the issue, but I'm left wondering whether this is a general problem with Chrome DevTools or if there's an underlying issue with how source maps are configured.